# localecompare return -1, is there other way to compare two strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I get a response from Ajax, and try to compare it with a string

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    console.log(response);
                    retvalT = response.localeCompare("true");
                    retvalF = response.localeCompare("false");
                    console.log(retvalT,retvalF)
                    if(response == "true"){
                        console.log("true")
                        return;
                    }else if(response == "false") {
                        console.log("false")
                        repeat();
                    }else{
                        console.log("compare failed")
                        return;
                    }
```

the `xmlhttp.responseText` from console is `true`, but the `retvalT`and `retvalF` are both `-1` and the final result is `compare failed`, why is this happening? thanks!

Comment: And you're sure it's a string and not a boolean, and `response.trim() == 'true'` comes to mind, why would you need localeCompare for the string `true` ?

Comment: You need to compare to Boolean True ? am I wrong ?

Comment: @Sekai - I'd say yes, you're wrong. The responseText is generally a string, but who knows ?

Comment: What are you getting in the console logs ?

Comment: try logging escape(response) to see if hidden or special chars are present.

Comment: @adeneo "compare failed", int the last "else". But I tried you suggestion, it works now, thanks!

Comment: So it was whitespace then, and trim() solved it.